# How is one-time pad secure against infinite computational resources?

Tags: information-theory, cryptography

Shannon's one-time pad is often used as an example of an information-theoretically secure system. An information-theoretically secure communication can not be broken by someone who has "infinite" computational resources.

If I am correct till here then let's say the message is $l$ bits long. Then, so is the key $S$. Can't someone just try all $2^l$ keys which is easy if they have infinite computational resources?

I guess, if the attacker can not spot the correct message than it makes sense but what if the message was English text? The key among the $2^l$ that produces valid English clearly can be found.

Comment: How do you know *which* English text message is the correct plaintext? There can (and there always will be) many such.

Comment: I guess I have a hard time imagining where/why/how that maybe.

Comment: Take any two English plaintexts of the same length, like "YOU ARE RIGHT" and "YOU ARE WRONG". Both of these can be encoded as "RFW POF PQDNE" with suitable keys.

Comment: May I ask what are the keys? Can I just obtain them by doing,

YOU ARE RIGHT $+$ RFW POF PQDNE $\mod 2$

and

YOU ARE WRONG $+$ RFW POF PQDNE $\mod 2$

Comment: @scribe more or less (assuming you meant "addition mod 26" as in the Vigenere cipher) If your key-generating process is equally likely to produce every possible length-$n$ key, then it's equally likely to produce every possible length-$n$ ciphertext out of a given plaintext, because there's one possible ciphertext per key and vice versa. Of course, this means that any non-randomness in key generation will let attackers guess which keys - and plaintexts - are more likely than the others.

Comment: Well, I meant turn both of those strings in binary using the ASCII table and then add them modulo two. Or, does this have an issue?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)? What part don't you understand?

Comment: I did not imagine the case where different plain-texts were possible so that was the part I did not quite understand or was not sure if I understood correctly. I do say that in my first comment when someone pointed that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Time Pad (OTP) requires uniform random key bits to be information-theoretically secure. Once the key is transmitted securely with a trusted carrier, than the messages transmitted between the two sides are secure as long as the keystream is never used again ( keywords: two-time pad, many-time pad, and crib-dragging).

In the correct usage of OTP, the attacker cannot learn anything about the message other than the message length of the transmitted message.

Once an eavesdropper obverserved an $\ell$ length OTP message, then all possible English text of size $\ell$ are possible candidates. The question is how can you distinguish?. For example, you expected that your enemy will attack tomorrow but don't know the time. You received a message of size 14 characters (Well, omit the encoding). Is it $\texttt{ATTACK AT DOWN}$ or $\texttt{ATTACK AT NOON}$? How you can decide which one? Why do we limit these two messages, because it is educational. What about $\texttt{WAIT FOR ORDER}$?. Usually the (military) messages are not this short long, so there will be numerous possibilities for each message. Even for two possible messages you fail to distinguish, how you can distinguish if there is more than one possibility?

You may some candidates of possible messages, however, this is your prejudice about the messages. If you look at the [historical exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad#Exploits), you will see that either weak random, or two time-pad for the exploits!

Now, why do you limit the message to meaningfull English? Maybe they are just coordinates? Maybe some other binary data!

To make it more interesting, let they sent a single bit! `1` for *attack* `0` for *wait* in every minute. Can you distinguish?

No matter what computainally power you have, you cannot distinguish the two messages!

Answer (score 0):

Given a cipher text of length $L$, and plain texts of the same length $L$ are equally likely (as all keys are of the same length and random). Any attacker has no way of telling which is right.